# Check Uniqueness of a Java Object, within some epsilon

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm trying to prune a 3D mesh by checking vertices for uniqueness. But because each vertex has some sort of error associated with it, two "similar" verts could actually be the same. e.g.

<1.9999999, 1, 3> could be the same vertex as <2.000001, 1, 3>

I have millions of vertices I need to check, so I was going to put all of the objects into a hash table and query to see if they are unique. Overriding isEqual is easy: take the abs of the difference between the two coordinates and divide by the magnitude of one. for example:

`if (Math.abs((x2-x2)/x1) < 0.0000001) return true;`

But how do I come up with a hashcode that will return the same for two effectively equal, but not exactly equal vertices?

I thought about quantizing the space, i.e. taking the floor to some decimal place for the entire set. But, then in my example above I would round to <1.999, 1, 3> and <2.000, 1, 3> for example.

Comment: It would probably be more robust to round the numbers *before* placing the vertices into the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how do I come up with a hashcode that will return the same for two effectively equal, but not exactly equal vertices?

In short, that's not possible.

If `hashcode(x) == hashcode(x + eps)` for all `x`, then it's also true that `hashcode(x + eps) == hashcode(x + 2*eps)` and so on.

The only way to satisfy this is `int hashcode() { return CONSTANT; }`, which is of limited use...

---

As a corollary, your `equals()` method is flawed too.  The [contract for `equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) requires that it be *transitive*, i.e. if `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(c)`, then `a.equals(c)`, for **any** `a`, `b`, `c`.  That is not the case for your definition.

This is going to lead to all sorts of subtle hell, as many of the standard Java collections, etc. rely on this.